# NoSuchFieldException when calling com.javabi.sizeof.MemoryUtil.sizeOf() in testng test run with eclipse Juno

Tags: java

I'm using OpenJDK 1.7.0_06-icedtea and get the following exception when calling sizeof when running testng test cases through the eclipse plugin:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUpBeforeMethod
com.javabi.sizeof.ClassDefinitionInitialisationException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: header
at com.javabi.sizeof.ClassDefinitionMap.<init>(ClassDefinitionMap.java:49)
at com.javabi.sizeof.MemoryUtil.sizeOf(MemoryUtil.java:133)
...
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it? Per the title, I'm running eclipse Juno, and some other coworkers who are running eclipse Juno have the same problem. Other coworkers have different configurations that work without throwing the exception run the same code.

Comment: use MemoryUtil.sizeOf and check

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your file?

`import com.javabi.sizeof.MemoryUtil;`

Second, in JUNO Specify the paths till the above location for the package.

Comment: No, that's not the call I'm making, I just truncated the com from the title of the post. I edited for clarity. This is code that works on other people's machines, and I actually have other co-workers who have exactly the same same problem I have after upgrading to eclipse Juno.

Comment: MemoryUtil is a class in the package com.javabi.sizeof

Comment: You are correct the source code seems to be present. Updated my answer

Comment: Yes, there are no compile errors. I'm running the same code as my coworkers.